# Create DataGrid in codebehind with bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

This is in a DataGrid in XAML:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NewContactList,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource panelTemplate}" 
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListTemplate}" 
DragDrop:DragDropHelper.IsDragSource="true" 
DragDrop:DragDropHelper.IsDropTarget="true" 
DragDrop:DragDropHelper.DragDropTemplate="{StaticResource DragTemplate}"
```

I want to create the DataGrid in Codebehind, but i know how to set the Bindings and my DragDrop:DragDropHelper

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myDataGrid = new DataGrid();
myDataGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("NewContactList") { UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
myDataGrid.SetResourceReference(DataGrid.ItemsPanelProperty, "panelTemplate");
myDataGrid.SetResourceReference(DataGrid.ItemTemplateProperty, "ListTemplate");
myDataGrid.SetValue(DragDropHelper.IsDragSourceProperty, True);
myDataGrid.SetValue(DragDropHelper.IsDropTargetProperty, True);
myDataGrid.SetResourceReference(DragDropHelper.DragDropTemplateProperty, "DragTemplate");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Dim dataGridObj As New DataGrid()

Dim itemsSourceBinding As New Binding("NewContactList")
itemsSourceBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
itemsSourceBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay

Dim itemsPanelResource = Me.FindResource("panelTemplate")
Dim itemTemplateResource = Me.FindResource("ListTemplate")
Dim dragDropTemplate = Me.FindResource("DragTemplate")

dataGridObj.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, itemsSourceBinding)
dataGridObj.ItemsPanel = CType(itemsPanelResource, ItemsPanelTemplate)
dataGridObj.ItemTemplate = CType(itemTemplateResource, DataTemplate)
dataGridObj.SetValue(DragDropHelper.IsDragSource, True)
dataGridObj.SetValue(DragDropHelper.IsDropTarget, True)
dataGridObj.SetValue(DragDropHelper.DragDropTemplate, CType(dragDropTemplate, DataTemplate))
```